# How do I properly design a database? Foreign Keys vs Secondary Keys?

Tags: database, database-design, foreign-keys

here are some generic tables, I am trying to fully understand how to properly setup databases tables. Are these setup correctly? I want to be able to lookup a user's Items and Item Details as fast as possible. FYI for this example ItemDetailsX do not share the same data fields.

I am a little bit stuck on Foreign Keys and Secondary keys. When do you use a Secondary Key vs a Foreign Key?

tbl_Users 1:* tbl_Item //relationship

tbl_Item 1:1 tbl_ItemDetail1 & tbl_ItemDetail2 // relationship

tbl_Item 1:N tbl_ItemDetail3 //releationship

**tbl_Users**

-UserID - PK

**tbl_Item**

-ItemID - PK

-UserID - FK

**tbl_ItemDetail1**

-ItemDetail1ID - PK //Do I even need this if I have ItemID? Its a 1:1 relationship with

-ItemID - FK

-Count

-Duration

-Frequency

**tbl_ItemDetail2**

-ItemDetail2ID - PK //Do I even need this if I have ItemID? Its a 1:1 relationship with

-ItemID - FK

-OnOff

-Temperature

-Voltage

**tbl_ItemDetail3**

-ItemDetail3ID - PK //Has a 1:N relationship

-ItemID - FK

-Contrived Value1

-Contrived Valu2

EDIT:

Thanks for the replies, I have updated my original post to properly reflect my database.

In the database that I am creating, the Item has ~9 item details. Each item details is 5-15 columns of data.

Having 1 table with like 100 columns does not make sense...?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Databases enforce 3 kinds of declarative integrity:

- Integrity of **domain** - field's type and CHECK constraint.
- Integrity of **key** - PRIMARY KEY or UNIQUE constraint.
- **Referential** integrity - FOREIGN KEY.

A *key* uniquely identifies rows in the table. All keys are logically equivalent, but for practical reasons one of them is chosen as "primary" and the rest are considered "alternate" (there are some complications involving NULLs, but let's not get into that here).

On the other hand, a FOREIGN KEY is as a kind of "pointer" from one table to another, where the DBMS itself guarantees this "pointer" can never ["dangle"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_pointer). The foreign key *references* the (primary or alternate) key in "parent" table, but the "child" endpoint does not need to be a key itself (and usually isn't).

- When a row is modified or deleted from the parent table, this change is either *cascaded* to the child table (ON [UPDATE/DELETE] [CASCADE/SET NULL/SET DEFAULT]) or the whole operation is blocked (ON [UPDATE/DELETE] RESTRICT).
- If a child is inserted or modified, it is checked against the parent table to make sure this new value exists there.

The constraints change the *meaning* of data. **Indexes**, on the other hand, do not change the meaning of data - they are here purely for *performance* reasons. Some databases will even allow you to have a key without an underlying index, although this is usually a bad idea performance-wise. An index underneath the primary key is called "primary index" and all other indexes are "secondary".

BTW, there is "secondary index" and there is "alternate key", but there is no such thing as "secondary key".

---

I'm not quite sure what is your design goal, but I'm guessing something like this would be a decent starting point:

[image]

I see no purpose in extracting details to separate tables **if** they are always in 1:1 relationship with the item.

---

### --- EDIT ---

Some questions you'll need to ask yourself before being able to arrive at optimal database design:

**Is there a real 1:1 relationship** between item and detail or is it actually 1:0..1 (i.e. some details are optional?).

- If 1:1, just using columns is the most natural representation. BTW, a decent DBMS will have no trouble handling 100 columns.
- If 1:0..1, you'll have to decide whether to use NULL-able columns, or separate tables. Just keep in mind that most DBMSes are really efficient in storing NULLs (typically just a small bitmap per row), so separating the data to a different table might not get you much, and in fact may substantially worsen the querying performance due increased need for JOINing.

**Are all detail kinds predetermined** (i.e. can you confidently say you won't need to add any new *kinds* of details later in the application's lifecycle)?

- If yes, just use columns.
- If no, adding columns on the large existing database can be expensive - whether it is expensive enough to warrant using separate table is up to you to measure.

*You could also consider generalizing all the details as name/value pairs and representing them within a single 1:N table (not shown here). This is very flexible and "evolvable", but has its own set of problems.*

**How do you intend to query the data?** This is a biggie and may influence substantially whether to go with "columns" or "separate table" approach, indexing etc...

---

BTW, the 1:0..1 with separate tables can be modeled like this...

[image]

...and 1:1 can be modeled like this...

[image]

...but this introduces circular dependency that must be handled in a special way (usually by [deferring](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10500_01/server.920/a96524/c22integ.htm#4666) one of the FOREIGN KEYs).

1:N details, of course, are another matter and are naturally modeled through separate tables.

---

Since you say "detail 1" and "detail 2" are 1:(0..)1 and "detail 3" is 1:N, your "updated" data model would probably look something like this:

[image]

BTW, the above model uses **identifying** relationships which result in more "natural" keys. **Non-identifying** relationships / surrogate keys approach would look like this:

[image]

Each approach has its advantages, but this post is becoming a little long already ;) ...

Comment: `I see no purpose in extracting details to separate tables if they are always in 1:1 relationship with the item.` What if the item had multiple values, would you consider introducing a linking (pivot) table?

Comment: I've seen "Secondary keys" used as a synonym for "secondary index". Not a good idea to mix the 2 concepts but that's what the OP probably means.

Comment: @MikePurcell If an item can have multiple details that are _not predetermined_ in advance, than this looks like a classic 1:N relationship to me (and we'd need additional table in the model above). If they _are_ predetermined, then we may just as well "cast them in stone" (as shown in the data model above). I'm not quite sure where you were going with pivot tables - is there something I don't see?

Comment: Not necessarily, I was just curious, if 'item' had a cardinality of 5, that I would create a 'lookup' table with each of the 5 values, then create a linking table between primary table and the item table, so if I ever need to update an 'item' value, I can do so across 5 rows, vs hundreds.

Comment: @MikePurcell Of course - if a given detail must take its value from the set of valid values, then you could have another table whose sole purpose is to contain valid values. You'd then have a M:N relationship between valid values table and details table, which is modeled through yet another ("link") table. Beside restricting detail values, this can also ease updating, as you already noted.

Comment: Agreed. Just wanted to needed to make sure for my own clarification.

Comment: I have updated my original question to better reflect what I am trying to accomplish. Thanks for the well written reply.

Comment: In the Item table you created above, is the User ID and Item ID a composite primary key?

Comment: @Mausimo Yes, {USER_ID,  ITEM_ID} is a composite primary key of ITEM. This may or may not be what you want (see identifying vs. non-identifying relationships).

Comment: @BrankoDimitrijevic Thank-you. This is a great answer! The 1:1 item details columns might change throughout the life of the application. It is probable that completely new item details will be added that do not currently exist. According to your answer, keeping all these details within 1 table is not be the best option because of this?

Comment: From a performance stand point, If I only want to query a specific set of details, but they are all in the 1 table, would it make sense then to have them in separate tables based on detail sets? So I would then query the required table only?

Comment: @Mausimo Probably not. By doing that, you are effectively storing a subset of detail "columns" to a separate table "heap" (assuming you don't use clustered tables), which may lower the I/O for range scans (if you are not already using [covering indexe](http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/glossary/covering-index) for you query), but you pay for JOINing. I'd just concentrate on proper indexing in the beginning.

Comment: @Mausimo There are other options for performance, such as clustering and partitioning - I warmly recommend reading [Use The Index, Luke!](http://use-the-index-luke.com/) if you are not familiar with the topic. Whatever you do, don't just rely on advice of other people (including me) - you are the only one who can actually **measure** on representative amounts of data before deciding!

Answer (score 0):

Your question cannot be answered in one simple SO post. There are a lot of things to consider when creating a database. The best thing I ever did to learn about databases and how to create them was to read a book called "Database Design For Mere Mortals" written by Michael Hernandez.

[See my post on Programmers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/18181/how-do-you-approach-database-design/18262#18262) to the question **How do you approach database design?**