# C# Int vs Byte performance & SQL Int vs Binary performance

Tags: c#, sql

In a C# windows app I handle HEX Strings. A single HEX string will have 5-30 HEX parts.

```
07 82 51 2A F1 C9 63 69 17 C1 1B BA C7 7A 18 20 20 8A 95 7A 54 5A E0 2E D4 3D 29
```

Currently I take this string and parse it into N number of integers using `Convert.ToInt32(string, 16)`. I then add these int values to a database. When I extract these values from the database, I extract them as Ints and then convert them back into HEX string.

Would it be better performance wise to convert these string to bytes and then add them as binary data types within the database?

EDIT:

The 5-30 HEX parts correspond to specific tables where all the parts make up 1 record with individual parts. For instance, if i had 5 HEX values, they correspond to 5 seperate columns of 1 record.

EDIT:

To clarify (sorry):

I have 9 tables. Each table has a set number of columns.

table1:30

table2:18

table3:18

table4:18

table5:18

table6:13

table7:27

table8:5

table9:11

Each of these columns in every table corresponds to a specific HEX value.

For example, my app will receive a "payload" of 13 HEX components in a single string format:  07 82 51 2A F1 C9 63 69 17 C1 1B BA C7. Currently I take this string and parse the individual HEX components and convert them to ints, storing them in an int array. I then take these int values and store them in the corresponding table and columns in the database. When I read these values I get them as ints and then convert them to HEX strings.

What I am wondering is If I should  conver the HEX string into a Byte array and store the bytes as SQL Binary variable types.

Comment: Your data model seem off. Does each "HEX part" have a precise meaning (it always refers to a particular table and particular column), or it can "wander" between tables/columns? I'm just trying to ascertain whether there is a deeper problem that needs to be solved first.

Comment: @BrankoDimitrijevic Check my edit please, I clarified my data model.

Comment: "The 5-30 HEX parts correspond to specific tables where all the parts make up 1 record with individual parts. For instance, if i had 5 HEX values, they correspond to 5 seperate columns of 1 record." This does not seem to be effective. Have you research more effective ways to store your data?  I assume 5-30 means 5 to 30 different Hex "parts".

Comment: @Ramhound Yes it means 5-30 different hex parts. It has to be this way, because of the data and what it corresponds to, I actually researched a lot into the database structure, but it must be this way. Thanks for the reply/

Comment: @Mausimo The question is do you even want to covert to byte array **at the database level** (you can always do it at the application level if necessary)? I'm still unclear whether "HEX parts" behave as FOREIGN KEYs towards these other tables, but **if they do**, you'll have to store them in separate columns - otherwise DBMS won't be able to enforce the referential integrity. You'll have plenty of columns (30 + 18 + ... + 11), but if that's the nature of the beast then so be it. Whether you actually need 30 columns in the `table1` (etc..) is a different issue...

Comment: @BrankoDimitrijevic All the HEX parts are just data, none of them are KEYS. The reason why I have them in separate columns is because each HEX part corresponds to a specific column which has a specific purpose... Also, Branko this database is related to the question you helped me with regarding the database design.

Comment: @Mausimo Whenever you say "related" the words "referential integrity" pop into my mind ;) But if you say they are not FOREIGN KEYs (which is different from just "keys", [as I already explained](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9335522/533120)) I believe you, so I suppose you can merge them together and store them as a byte array. BTW, have you considered, _not_ storing them at all? After all, you are effectively repeating the data that is already in the database, violating the [DRY principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DRY), which might, but then again might _not_ be justified performance-wise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well in terms of performance, you should of course *test* both ways.

However, in terms of *readability*, if this is just arbitrary data, I'd certainly suggest using a byte array. If it's *actually* meant to represent a sequence of integers, that's fine - but why would you represent an arbitrary byte array using a collection of 4-byte integers? It doesn't fit in well with anything else:

- You have to consider padding if your input data isn't a multiple of 4 bytes
- It's a pain to work with in terms of reading and writing the data with streams
- It's not clear how you're storing the integers in the database, but I'd *expect* a blob to be more efficient if you're just trying to store the whole thing

I would suggest writing the code the more *natural* way, keeping your data close to the kind of thing it's really trying to represent, and then measuring the performance. If it's good enough, then you don't need to look any further. If it's not, you'll have a good basis for tweaking.

Comment: @Mausimo: So why don't you have a table with 5 columns? If the columns all have different meaning, that makes a lot more sense. It's still not really clear what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, by far. Inserting many rows is far worse than inserting few bigger rows.

Answer (score 1):

A data model often depends not on just how you want to *write*, but also how you want to *find* and read the data.

Some considerations:

- If you ever have a need to **find** a particular a "HEX part", even when not at the start of the "HEX string", then each "HEX part" will need to be in a separate row so a database index can pick it up.
- Depending on your DBMS/API, it may not be easy to **seek** through a BLOB or byte array. This may be important for loading non-prefix "HEX parts" or performing modifications in the middle of the "HEX string".
- If the "HEX string" needs to be a PRIMARY, UNIQUE or FOREIGN KEY, or needs to be searchable by prefix, then you'll typically need a database type that is actually indexable (BLOBs typically aren't, but most DBMSes have alternate types for smaller byte arrays that *are*).

All in all, a byte array is probably what you need, but beware of the considerations above.